# Putting a command inside awk to merge columns of different files

Tags: text-processing, awk, command-line, cut

I have a file.txt for example (it does not have the same number of columns for each row):

```
1 2 3 4
5 5 6 
7 7 7 7 9 10
```

I have another file (file2.txt) that contains 2 columns

```
    a b
    c d
    e f
```

I use this command:

```
awk '{print $1,$(cut -f2 file2.txt)}' file.txt > final.txt
```

I want to take the second column of file2.txt and add it between columns 1 and 2 of file1.txt.

Ex. of results:

```
1 d 2 3 4 
5 d 5 6
7 f 7 7 7 9 10
```

I want also maintaining all the remaining columns of file1.txt

Comment: Should that be a "b" on the first line of your desired results?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's a b

Comment: Then please edit your question to fix that typo. Also, does file2 really have leading whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure `awk`:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{c[NR]=$2}
    FNR!=NR{$1 = $1 OFS c[FNR]; print}
' file2 file
```

Output:

```
1 b 2 3 4 
5 d 5 6 
7 f 7 7 7 9 10
```

Comment: You could also write `FNR != NR {$1 = $1 OFS c[FNR]; print}` but that forces awk to rebuild $0. I don't know which would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

How about a little cut'n'paste?

```
paste -d" " <(cut -d" " -f1 file1.txt) <(cut -d" " -f2 file2.txt) <(cut -d" " -f2- file1.txt)
```

Comment: from OPs input, it must be `-f6` for file2 ...

Comment: I don't understand your comment. "I have another file (file2.txt) that contains 2 columns" -- where does field 6 come from?

Comment: I copy-pasted the example file which has 4 spaces in front, and `cut` does not ignore those. So first 4 fields are empty. Not sure if it was by purpose or unintended,

Comment: Oh I see that. I was assuming there is no leading space and edited that out on my system. Can replace middle cut with `<(awk '{print $2}' file2.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

While some implementations of awk do allow reading from piped sub-processes<sup>1</sup>, in this case I'd suggest reading the whole line from the second file, and doing the field splitting inside awk:

```
$ awk '(getline line < "file2.txt") > 0 {split(line,a); $1 = $1 FS a[2]} 1' file1.txt
1 b 2 3 4
5 d 5 6
7 f 7 7 7 9 10
```

Alternatively, you could consider using `paste` and `cut`, avoiding awk altogether

---

1. see for example [Using getline from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fPipe)

Answer (score 0):

With Perl, you read a line from  file 1 then read a line from file2 via stdin. Afterwards stitch the lines in the desired order.

```
 $ perl -pale '$_ = join "\t", shift @F, <STDIN> =~ /\S\s+(\S+)/, @F' file1.txt < file2.txt
```

Output:

```
 1  b   2   3   4
 5  d   5   6
 7  f   7   7   7   9   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{b[FNR]=$2;next}{print $1,b[FNR],$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' file2.txt  file1.txt
```

Comment: The main problem here being that file.txt "does not have the same number of columns for each row" so hard-coding 7 fields is a limited solution.